# How to finish TabGroupActivity from another TabGroupActivity in android

Tags: android

I've three tabs which has Tab group activity for each tab. Now I want to finish second tabgroup activity(parent & all child below that) from third tab.
For ex.

> Tab1->parent1->child1->child1
>       Tab2->Parent2->child2->child2
>       Tab3->Parent3->child3->child3

I want to finish Tab2 tabGroupActivity from child3. How could I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: TabGroupActivity? Android document don't have such class.

Answer (score 0):

I have finished my Activity by overriding this method:

```
@override
protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: If i use ur code.,i got error as  java.lang.StackOverflowError
05-28 18:18:09.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12337):  at android.app.Activity.onPause(Activity.java:1211)